# SDL/SDL.h file not found in Karol the Robot

Tags: c, macos, sdl, clion, karel

I tried to run this Github repository called 'Karel the Robot' for my work in university:
[Karel the Robot for MacOS](https://github.com/fwheinz/karel_clion_macosx)

I use macOS Monterey V12.2.1 and run this through an IDE called Clion. I tried to work on the projects via the built in VCS option of the IDE and also tried to simply download and open it from the desktop. Whenever I try to run the basic project (without any additions or changes made by me) I get this error:

```
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/cc  -I/Users/nox/CLionProjects/karel/include -I/usr/local/include -g -arch arm64 -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX12.3.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=12.2 -std=gnu11 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/StarterProject.dir/HelloKarel.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/StarterProject.dir/HelloKarel.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/StarterProject.dir/HelloKarel.c.o -c /Users/nox/CLionProjects/karel/HelloKarel.c
In file included from /Users/nox/CLionProjects/karel/HelloKarel.c:10:
In file included from /Users/nox/CLionProjects/karel/include/karel.h:3:
In file included from /Users/nox/CLionProjects/karel/include/structs.h:48:
/Users/nox/CLionProjects/karel/include/config.h:1:10: fatal error: 'SDL/SDL.h' file not found #include <SDL/SDL.h>
```

I understand that he can't find the SDL.h file on my system so I installed and reinstalled it with brew by doing the following:
`brew install sdl sdl_image sdl_ttf`
and `brew reinstall sdl sdl_image sdl_ttf`

Nothing seemed to work for me. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: Installing sdl installs the runtime part. You need the dev package for the headers.

Comment: It is possible the `SDL` header file were installed in a path not in your includes. Unfortunatly, I am not familiar with Mac and `brew` and I don't know where it puts all the files, but try changing the include path to `SDL2/SDL.h`. SDL has been on version 2 for several years now, so the headers may be there. if not, try `brew install sdl2`, the older version may be broken.

Comment: [SDL2 Development Libraries/Mac OS](https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-2.0.20.dmg)

Comment: @stark how do I do that?

Comment: @DavidSzöke Did you look at [the SDL download page](https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php) under _Development Libraries_?